# JavaScript - Sequence of letters

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, google-chrome, ecmascript-2016

I want to create the function which should return n-th string from the sequence

`a, b, c, ... , z, aa, ab, ... , az, ba, ... , zz, aaa, ...`

for given number n (indexes start from zero).

This is the current my function:

```
const charCode = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);

function identName(a){
  var b = '';

  while(a){
    b = String.fromCharCode(charCode + a % 26) + b;
    a = a / 26 | 0;
  }

  return b || 'a';
}
```

There are 26 letters, so I divide by 26 and each time I concatenate char code of remainder (modulo 26) to the string `b`. However this is the output:

`a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ba bb bc bd be ...`

As you can see, two letter strings starts from `ba`. I tried to decrease by 1 in each iteration, but then the result is like this:

`a a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y a' aa ab ac ad ...`

There are string `a` two times and there is no `z`. What am I doing wrong? How to properly generate this sequence in optimal and fast way?

## Edit

I really don't see what is unclear in my question. I simply want a function which is called like this `identName(0)` and returns `"a"`, when called like this `identName(1)` returns `"b"`, etc..., when called like this: `identName(26)` returns `"aa"` and so on. How can it be described simplier. I really don't udnerstand what is unclear here... :/

Comment: is that your full code? how are you calling identName()? Do you really need to use charcode?

Comment: is that what you're outputting?  What are you doing? * *confused* * What do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
const charCode = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);

var identName = function (a) {
  var b = [a], sp, out, i, div;

    sp = 0;
    while(sp < b.length) {
        if (b[sp] > 25) {
            div = Math.floor(b[sp] / 26);
            b[sp + 1] = div - 1;
            b[sp] %= 26;
        }
        sp += 1;
    }

    out = "";
    for (i = 0; i < b.length; i += 1) {
        out = String.fromCharCode(charCode + b[i]) + out;
    }

    return out;
}
```

Essentially you were skipping over the 0 positions each time you got to the transition for example 27 -> 0,0 rather than 1,0.

Comment: Your code gives the wrong result for `a = 2 ** 62`. The result should be `"avhlgfirxfedoe"` while your script outputs `"avhlgfirxfedaa"`. It can be fixed by replacing `b[sp] -= div * 26;` with `b[sp] %= 26;`.

Comment: @CarlJohnson Updated, I did not test out that far, I like that solution of using the module. Makes more sense anyhow.

Comment: @CarlJohnson I expect that is due to a loss of integer precision? Which will cause a problem again at a certain point. At that point you could attempt to do this with a different number base, strings as input, or using a package like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/long